# How to assign an object some keys by javaScript spread syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have the following object:

```
var inv = {roles: {"xxx00": {roleId: "zzzz33"}}, assign: [1, 2, 3] }
```

This is the result:

```
{ roles: { "1234": {roleId: null}, "5678": {roleId: null}}}
```

I need to consolidate the object with this result:

```
{roles: {"1234": {roleId: null}, "5678": {roleId: null}, "xxx00": {roleId: "zzzz33"}}, assign: [1, 2, 3] }
```

And I need to get that with the spread syntax

Any idea how the syntax should be to get this result without losing the original roleId?

Comment: I would try something along the lines of `({...a, ...b})` where `a` and `b` are your two objects.

Comment: The `...` construct is *not* an "operator". It's a syntactic element but not part of the expression grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

```
const consolidated = {...inv, roles: {...inv.roles, ...result.roles} };
```

Assuming you only want to merge your result roles with the inv var roles, this will create consolidated based on inv but with result roles merged in inv roles.

Answer (score 2):

Below are two examples one with no object mutation, the other with.

```js
let inv = {roles: {"xxx00": {roleId: "zzzz33"}}, assign: [1, 2, 3] };
let res = { roles: { "1234": {roleId: null}, "5678": {roleId: null}}};

// create new object to spec, no mutation.
let combine = { roles: { ...inv.roles, ...res.roles, }, assign: [ ...inv.assign ] };
console.log(combine);

// mutate original object.
console.log(inv);
inv.roles = {  ...inv.roles, ...res.roles, };
console.log(inv);
```